# Hide multiple span classes on image hover with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an effect where when one hovers on an image a number of span classes, in this case named .highlight, fade out and then fade back in on mouse out.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {

    var trigger = $('.imglist img'),
        target = $('.highlight');

        trigger.hover(function() {
          target.fadeOut('slow');
        }); //end inner function

 }); //end outer function
```

HTML

```
    <span class="highlight">Opera Krakowska</span>
```

(I have many titles throughout the website with this class applied to them.)

```
    <div class="imglist">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/projects/operakrakowska/operakrakowska_01.png" width="750px"></a>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's not working in this moment? Also, in order to get some useful answers, I suggest to post a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your jquery library is loaded???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1)

Try this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLr3ggvt/1/)

```
$(function() {

    var trigger = $('.imglist img'),
        target = $('.highlight');

        trigger.hover(function() {//when mouse over
            target.fadeOut('slow');
        },function(){//when mouse out
            target.fadeIn('slow');
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ufottqh0/

```
$('.imglist').find('.highlight').css('opacity', 1);  

$('.imglist .hoverImg').hover(  
   function(){  
      $('.highlight').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
   },  
   function(){  
      $('.highlight').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
   }    
);
```